# How to implement a multi-step form in Django admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-formwizard

My task is to give the opportunity to fill out the form in several steps, processing the result of each step.

I found an [example](https://elo80ka.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/using-a-formwizard-in-the-django-admin/) of what I need, but this example of 2009

I know about [wizard form](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html), but I do not understand how to implement it in Dango admin.

I tried to do this:

```
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyCustomAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = [
        url(r'^my_view/$', Wizard.as_view([Form1, Form2]))        
    ]
    return my_urls + urls
```

But got an error:

> AttributeError at /admin/сustom/custommodel/my_view/
>
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Perhaps `Wizard form` are not the best option. But I do not know how to implement the task set otherwise

Answer (score 3):

I have the same requirement, and I m looking into https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

It was last updated in February 2017, so it is possibly up to date?

Comment: I refused this idea and now I'm not even looking for ways to implement this.

The only solution I found was https://github.com/narnikgamarnikus/django_reverse_admin

But be careful, it does not work with the datetype filed, and so, after saving, does not bind the object to the form, but the save occurs.

In any case - this is a bad way, but it somehow works

Comment: There is an update to this for django 2.* [here] (https://pypi.org/project/django-reverse-admin)

Comment: I have just (Oct 2020) used django-formtools to implement a wizard on a django 3 project and it worked very nicely. Well-designed api that handles the boilerplate and you just implement the Forms and business logic, and can reuse ModelForms and other admin bits and bobs.

Comment: @Uberdude Any chance you could share the details of what you did in an answer here? It'd really help me (and others like us) out.

Comment: @Uberdude : can one bake this form tool directly within the admin panel? I don’t want to create a separate page for this. I want to give a wizard type look within the admin panel itself for saving data to my connected data models